# Python :: How to open a page in the Non Default browser

Tags: python, browser

I was trying to create a simple script to open a locally hosted web site for testing the css in 2 or more browsers.  The default browser is IE7 and it opens the page fine but when I try to open a non default browser such as Firefox or Arora it just fails.

I am using the webbrowser module and have tried this several way as detailed in various sites across the web.

Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: how did you try to open it using other browsers?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I was using the webbrowser.get() call passing the various names for the browsers I was trying to open.  I also tried passing the full path and then using the webbrowser.register() function.

The error message I got after some digging about was thrown on line 52 of the webbrowser module and was thrown because it could not find the specified browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt's right and it's a pretty useful module to know...

[18.1. subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

```
IDLE 2.6.2      
>>> import subprocess
>>> chrome = 'C:\Users\Ted\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
>>> chrome_args = 'www.rit.edu'
>>> spChrome = subprocess.Popen(chrome+' '+chrome_args)
>>> print spChrome.pid
2124
```

Comment: This is correct, but you should quote the path and maybe even the URL.

Comment: I will give this a go.  Thanks I hadn't thought about doing it this way!

Answer (score 1):

The [subprocess module](http://www.python.org/doc/2.4/lib/module-subprocess.html) should provide what you want if you feed subprocess the path to the browser. Note that you need Python 2.4 or later to use subprocess, but that's common nowadays.

Update - code for a method to call Chrome, while opening a passed in URL:

```
def startChrome(url):
    """ Calls Chrome, opening the URL contained in the url parameter. """
    executable = 'path-to-chrome'    # Change to fit your system
    cmd = ' '.join([executable, url])
    browswer_proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as I say above I hadn't thought about doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `get()` function of `webbrowser` doesn't work properly. In that case, you can use `register()` to define your own browser.

```py
import webbrowser
browser_path="<path_to_your_browser_executable>"
webbrowser.register('my_browser', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(browser_path))
webbrowser.get('my_browser').open("stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

This basically boils down to:

```
- run 'firefox "url"'
- run 'iexplore "url"'
- run 'other_browser "url"'
```

I don't know enough python to know how the system() call is implemented there but it should be quite simple.